# mpd cannot find existing music files

Tags: 16.04, files, services, music-player, mpd

I have some music files in `~/Music`:

```
sunqingyao@sunqingyao-MacBookAir:~$ ls /home/sunqingyao/Music
Bastion Original Soundtrack     This War of Mine OST
Beholder OST                    Titan Souls Special Edition Content
Hyper Light Drifter soundtrack  Transistor Soundtrack
Stellaris soundtrack
```

After successfully doing `sudo apt install ncmpcpp mpd`, I tried to configure them.

`~/.ncmpcpp/config`:

```
mpd_host = localhost
mpd_port = 6600
mpd_music_dir = /home/sunqingyao/Music
```

`/etc/mpd.conf`:

```
music_directory                 "/home/sunqingyao/Music"
......
```

Then I launched the music player with `sudo service mpd restart && ncmpcpp`, but it seems that `mpd` cannot find my songs.

[image]

Comment: please try to replace the "~/Music" with your full-path

Comment: @Yaron Still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself: you should use

```
mpd_music_dir = "/home/sunqingyao/Music"
```

instead of

```
mpd_music_dir = /home/sunqingyao/Music
```

The quotation marks mustn't be omitted.